# Codeigniter mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have my model set like this, so that it gets all the data from the table "tests" in the previously specified database:

```
<?php class Get_db extends CI_Model {


public function getData()
{
    $query = $this->db->get("tests");

    return $query->result();
}}?>
```

and after I loaded all this data in my controller, and passed it to my view, I got this function in my view:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($records as $rec) {
        echo $rec->id."  ".$rec->name."   ";

     ?>
```

and all the ids and names in my database will be posted where i want.

But what if I wanted to be more selective. Let's say that I've got a param. in my db called "color" some of my rows will have color set to (for example) red, and some others to blue.

How can I display in my view just the rows with color=red?
Or, more exacty, how can I tell php to get the data just of the rows that have color=red?

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select, look at `get_where()`

Comment: you just need a simple `where` in your query. let us know if you are able to figure it out

Comment: It went as smoothly as honey. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter uses [an ActiveRecord library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html), be sure to read the documentation as it is clearly stated there.

You can use `$this->db->get_where()` to filter on a `WHERE` clause. In your case:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('tests', array('color' => 'red'));
```